# Setter for a SQLAlchemy hybrid_property that queries from a joined table

Tags: python, properties, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to model a task with a set of statuses in SQLAlchemy.  I have the following:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

Base = declarative_base()

class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'task'

    statusId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('status.id'))
    status = relationship('Status', backref=backref('status'), lazy='joined')

    @hybrid_property
    def statusName(self):
        return self.status.name

class Status(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'status'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(32), unique=True)
```

The status table is populated in the database and is fairly static:

```
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | unassigned   |
|  2 | pending      |
|  3 | working      |
|  4 | failed       |
|  5 | done         |
+----+--------------+
```

What I want to be able to do is refer to the status names by name and not by id.  So when a Task's status changes, I want to write `task.statusName = 'working'` instead of `task.statusId = 3`.  I'm not sure how to make a setter for `statusName` that does this.  Is this against the design of an ORM, because the definition of the setter depends on the current rows present in the `Status` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your database structure slightly to achieve the intended effect.  It seems that you have a natural key in status.  The name is effectively the primary key.

```
class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'task'

    status = Column(String(32), ForeignKey('status.name'))

class Status(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'status'

    name = Column(String(32), primary_key=True)
```

You could then easily set the status as such:

```
task = Task()
task.status = 'error'
```

This would also raise exceptions if the status was not available because there is still a foreign key constraint.